# Mathematica doesn't want simplify the square root of the square even under assumptions

Tags: simplifying-expressions, syntax

Suppose a simple function

```
f[x_,y_] = Sqrt[(x-y)^2]+Sqrt[(y-x)^2]
```

Knowing that $x>y>0$, without any commands like `Simplify` one can obtain `(x-y)` by using the `Sqrt[(x-y)^2]-> (x-y)` and `Sqrt[(x-y)^2]-> (x-y)`:

```
f[s2, m2] /. {Sqrt[(x-y)^2] -> x-y, 
  Sqrt[(y-x)^2] -> x-y}
```

This might be used for the case of complicated functions involving many terms and other, when the `Simplify` command takes so much time. I tried to use it for one complicated function defined dynamically, but there was no result.

What is the reason and how to construct formal rule replacing the expressions like $\sqrt{(x-y)^2}$?

P.S. PowerExpand cripples the expression for the function...

Comment: Perhaps you rejected [`PowerExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PowerExpand) because you used it without asumptions? For your example, ``PowerExpand[Sqrt[(x-y)^2] + Sqrt[(y-x)^2], Assumptions-> x>y]`` works well.

Comment: @CarlWoll : My complicated function after using the PowerExpand acquires some strange summands involving imarinary units and Args (even under assumptions) and expanding log[a/b] to log[a] - log[b], so I would like to avoid it.

Comment: An example where PowerExpand is lacking would be useful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can target the `Sqrt[..]` expressions for simplification like this:

```
Sqrt[(x - y)^2] + Sqrt[(y - x)^2] /. 
 rt : (Sqrt[_] | 1/Sqrt[_]) :> Simplify[rt, x > y]
(*  2 x - 2 y  *)
```

Perhaps that is what you're after.

I've often done such targeted simplification, when the size of the main expression leads to a combinatorial explosion of rabbit trails for `Simplify` to follow.  You can also use [`ExcludedForms`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExcludedForms.html) to ***prevent*** `Simplify` from touching a subexpression, in case you want a somewhat complementary process (thanks to Carl Woll for pointing out this option).  You can combine these in a sequence of steps to slowly get an expression down to a manageable size.

Comment: Simplify has the [`ExcludedForms`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExcludedForms) option that you can use to exclude patterns that shouldn't be simplified.